# Navigate To at start up simulation

Tags: anylogic

When I run the model, I want my model to go to the viewarea of the simulation parameters in the agent of this user interface. So at the simulation and java actions I added this by the next code (also a screenshot is added at the bottom):

```
root.uI_startUP.SimulationParameters.navigateTo();
```

The strange thing is when I run the model for the first time, he goes for like 1 second to this view area, but then automatically returns to the main agent. When I stop the model and restart it again (and keep the run window open), this problem is not happening and it is staying in the good user-interface agent view area.

What could be the reason behind this? and how can this be solved.

[image]

Added later:

At the moment I fixed it by creating an event which is triggered by the variable start==true, and after that navigates to the interface and sets this value to false. see figure below

[image]

This works, and seems to be a solution.

But I'm still curious why the first method is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the code in "Initial experiment setup" that messes here.

Remove both code snippets and only call `uI_startUP.SimulationParameters.navigateTo()` on the "On startup" of `Main`.

This is how you should do it anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried this but it is still going to the main agent after a few second.

Comment: Did you remove all other `navigateTo(...)` calls in the model and in the experiment setup?

Comment: You probably create the agent programmatically on start. Maybe move the `navigateTo()` inside the agent itself into its "on startup" code section. Preface it with an "if" statement to only trigger if this is the agent to be used, based on the parameter on Main

Comment: Yes I deleted all the navigateTo() at startups in the model, Also tried to put it in the agent type of the user interface but both methods does not solve the problem.

Comment: When I unchecked the skip experiment screen and run the model , it all seems to work. But when I check this it does not work anymore .

Comment: use an event on main that triggers the "navigateTo" code 1ms after the model start. Not elegant but may help

Comment: I indeed did this and it worked, see start post . But still finding it strange haha.

Comment: it is driven by how your agents are instantiated and your param setup. Not strange, actually :)